# How to Customize Linux for custom design from Beaglebone

Tags: linux, embedded, arm, bootloader, beagleboard

I am planning to build a custom hardware /Derivative from designs of Open source hardwares like Beagle bone black.

How to Customize Linux for custom design from open hardwares like Beaglebone?

- We start with doing the circuit schematic --> route and do the pcb--> test hardware -->
  then where to start the software with for this custom board?
- How are new or extra peripherals added to the custom hardware be
  mapped to its Linux OS/bootloader?
- How does linux for example know i am using a extra usb host or pin
  supported peripheral in my custom design in place of few gpio pins on processor as in case of original design?

Thanks

Comment: This seems very on-topic to me... My understanding is it's asking how to port the Linux Kernel to a custom embedded device.

Comment: If you make peripheral changes to the board, you'll have to make changes to the kernel. A good starting point may be here: https://code.google.com/p/beagle-borg/source/browse/kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/board-am335xevm.c

Comment: @TimM Great info. 1.Is that file a board support package? 2.Can you clarify if boot-loaders like u-boot for beagle also needs to be customized as they initialize hardware?

Comment: 1. Yes, that code is board specific. 2. Yes, search for "porting u-boot" to find a bunch of information on the process.

Comment: Thanks @TimM .Just one more question to close my doubts, bear with me. Am i right in assuming this- In general for custom boards 1.We port the boot-loader and kernel for our custom board. 2.We flash the bootloader to a NAND memory. 3.The processor on power on goes to this NAND ROM to run the bootloader which nitializes hardware and loads linux kernel to memory. 4.linux takes control and flow continues.

Comment: That is correct. There is documentation for how the bootloader needs to interface with the Linux kernel in the source under Documentation/arm/Booting, but I'm not sure how up-to-date it is.